# Access Locust Host attribute - Locust 1.0.0+

Tags: python-3.x, performance-testing, locust

I had previously asked and solved the problem of dumping stats using an older version of locust, but the `setup` and `teardown` methods were removed in locust 1.0.0, and now I'm unable to get the host (base URL).

I'm looking to print out some information about requests after they've run. Following the docs at https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html, I have an `request_success` listener inside my sequential task set - some rough sample code below:

```
class SearchSequentialTest(SequentialTaskSet):

    @task
    def search(self):
        path = '/search/tomatoes'
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
        unique_identifier = uuid.uuid4()
        data = {
            "name": f"Performance-{unique_identifier}",
        }

        with self.client.post(
                path,
                data=json.dumps(data),
                headers=headers,
                catch_response=True,
        ) as response:
            json_response = json.loads(response.text)
            self.items = json_response['result']['payload'][0]['uuid']

            print(json_response)


    @events.request_success.add_listener
    def my_success_handler(request_type, name, response_time, response_length, **kw):
       print(f"Successfully made a request to: {self.host}/{name}")
```

But I cannot access the `self.host` - and if I remove it I only get a relative url.

How do I access the base_url inside a TaskSet's event hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access the base_url inside a TaskSet's event hooks?

You can do it by accessing the class variable directly in your request handler:

```
print(f"Successfully made a request to: {YourUser.host}/{name}")
```

Or you can use absolute URLs in your test (task) like this:

```
    with self.client.post(
        self.user.host + path,
        ...
```

Then you'll get the full url to your request listener.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but when I put `print (self.user.host)` inside `my_success_handler` I get `
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.
if I change the function declaration to `def my_success_handler(self, request_type, name, response_time, response_length, **kw):` and rerun I get `TypeError: my_success_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I'm trying to write stats out to a file in a specific format, which is why I chose the success event hook - if there's another way to accomplish that (and be able to print host url) I'm open to that.

Comment: either follow my first suggestion or my second one, you're kind of doing both :) (self.user.host is available in your TaskSet, but not in your event handler)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, you’re adding the event inside your TaskSet. Actuallt, it should be done at the top level. Doing it inside your TaskSet will make no difference (it will not give you access to self)

Comment: At the top level do you mean inside the `HttpUser` class? That also doesn't seem to have access to self: `TypeError: my_success_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: what I’m saying is that it will never get access to self. put it at top level, not inside anything at all, to avoid tricking yourself that it might.

Comment: Thanks for your patience in sticking with me! Got it working now! Sincerely appreciate the help.